# Dereferencing member of a templated typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, dereference

I am using a library that has:

```
typedef std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<std::wstring>* > XmlRecord_t;
```

When I iterate on this map, I create variables such as:

```
std::wstring& key( mapIter->first );
std::vector<std::wstring>* values( mapIter->second );
```

which is all fine. Then I want to iterate on the values, so I have a `for` loop such as:

```
for( std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator it = vals->cbegin();... )
```

which is fine and works well.

Now, as a curiosity only, I'd like to reuse the library's `typedef` names, in case the `typedef` definition changes, or for cleanliness. In other words, I'd like to use:

```
typedef XmlRecord_t::mapped_type VecPtr;
VecPtr values( mapIter->second )
```

instead of:

```
std::vector<std::wstring>* values( mapIter->second );
```

That works so far. The only issue comes from the `for` loop. My `typedef` is a pointer to `vector`, not just a `vector`. So I cannot use that `typedef` to replace:

```
std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator
```

in any way I know of.

Hence, my question generalizes to: if you have in a library (code I do not allow you to modify):

```
typedef map<KEY, T*> Map2Ptrs
```

how can you use `Map2Ptrs` in your code to get `T` (without the pointer)? To make a `typedef` of type `T`?

Obviously, the library authors should have created:

```
typedef std::vector<std::wstring>  XmlRecordVals;
typedef std::map<std::wstring, XmlRecordVals* > XmlRecord_t;
```

instead. But I only have the original XmlRecord_t above to work with ;(

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use `auto`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required to outline the problems with your code as required here please!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Map2Ptrs` is always an `std::map`, its key and mapped type can be inspected with `Map2Ptrs::key_type` and `Map2Ptrs::mapped_type` respectively.

The pointer can be removed from a type with `std::remove_pointer_t` (requires C++14 and `#include<type_traits>`), e.g.:

```
using T = std::remove_pointer_t<Map2Ptrs::mapped_type>;
```

In modern C++ you probably should not specify the iterator types by hand, they can easily be deduced:

```
for( auto it = vals->cbegin();... )
```

Furthermore, there is also the range-for, which eliminates the need to specify the iterators manually and has much nicer syntax:

```
for(const auto& x : *vals) { /* Do something with x */ }
```

And since C++17, for the map structured bindings can be used:

```
for(const auto& [key, vals] : theMap) {
    /* Do something with key and vals */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `std::remove_pointer`. Example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
print_is_same<int, std::remove_pointer<int*>::type>();  // true
```

So if your aliased the pointer to vector type then you'd get the iterator via:

```
using Xml_const_iterator = std::remove_pointer<XmlRecord_t>type::const_iterator;
```

Though I would strongly suggest you to change the actual alias to remove the pointer instead.